# get node js requests

Tags: node.js, json, request, get

It is required to receive requests from the required IP addresses at the link 127.0.0.1:3000/test in the get format on nodejs and get the json file. When sending a GET request, a 404 error is generated according to the code below

```
http.createServer((request, response) => {
   console.log(request.url);
   console.log(request.method);
   console.log(request.headers);
   console.log(request.socket.remoteAddress);
    if (request.method === "GET") {
        console.log(`Requested address: ${request.url}`);
        const filePath = request.url.substr(1);
        fs.access(filePath, fs.constants.R_OK, err => {
            if (err) {
                response.statusCode = 404;
                response.end("Resourse not found!");
            } else {
                fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(`Requested address: ${request.url}`);
    }
}).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started at 3000");
});
```

Comment: Where did u define the route?

Comment: Nowhere, I don't know how

Comment: You should take a look at express!
It will save you some pain

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using express.

```js
const app = require('express')();
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/test', (request, response), async () => {
  fs.createReadStream('./test.json').pipe(response);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Or if you're looking for a more dynamic approach.

```js
app.get('/:filePath', (request, response), async () => {
  const { filePath } = req.params;
  fs.access(filePath, fs.constants.R_OK, err => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send('Resourse not found!');
        } else {
            fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When sending a GET request, it gives a 404 error

Comment: Mind sending the code in a pastebin post?